# Looking for a neat functional way of carrying out this return

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Is there a neat functional way of carrying out this return without first assigning the value to the variable?

Note: The first get is guaranteed of returning a valuable from the map and hence the "!!".
The second get is not guaranteed and can thus return null.

Thank you

```
fun isHidden(digitsChosen: String, digitNext: Char): Boolean {
    val middlePosition = positionsHidden.get(digitsChosen.last())!!.get(digitNext)
    return middlePosition != null && digitsChosen.dropLast(1).contains(middlePosition).not()
}
```

Comment: Functional programming isn't about not declaring variables at all. Even Haskell has `let`. Your code is fine with the `middlePosition` variable there. This might also be a better question for Code Review Stack Exchange, by the way

Comment: I think from a functional perspective you should also consider the role of `positionsHidden` in your function. If that map or its content is mutable, then the result of `isHidden` would depend on its input + the state of the surrounding environment, so `isHidden` wouldn't be a pure function

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use something like this:

```kotlin
fun isHidden(digitsChosen: String, digitNext: Char): Boolean {
    return positionsHidden.get(digitsChosen.last())?.let {
        it.get(digitNext)?.let {
            digitsChosen.dropLast(1).contains(it).not()
        } ?: false
    } ?: false
}
```

Which seems to be a little bit NPE-proof, but more clumsy.

Anyway, I would recommend you to replace `!!.get` with `?.get` and deal with `null` explicitly.

Comment: You can remove the `?: false` from the nested let